# Show text dataframe rows containing others things than characters and white space (Python)

Tags: python, database, nlp, data-cleaning

I got a Python dataframe which has "Text" and "ID" columns.
I would like to be sure that each row of "Text" column contains only characters and white space.
If it's not the case (digit, special character, etc.), I would like to print all text and their ID in order to identify where is the problem.
Any idea to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be better to use regex but you could try this:

```
x = [None] * len(df['Text']) # create list with same length as df
i = 0
for text in df['Text']:
    if  all(j.isalpha() or j.isspace() for j in text):
        x[i] = False # contains letters and whitespace
    else:
        x[i] = True # contains digits, special xters
    i += 1

no_text_df = df[x] # contains all rows with digits and special xters in Text column
```

If your dataFrame has a very large number of rows, applying regex may be a faster option but this shouuld work as well.